# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{2n!}{2s\cdot(2s+1)\cdot(2s+2)\cdots(2s+n)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Find the original f function if it's Laplace transform $F(s)$ is equal to :
$$\frac{2n!}{2s\cdot(2s+1)\cdot(2s+2)\cdots(2s+n)}$$

This is looking tricky and I don't know how to start it

The correct answe should be (but it could be wrong it happens in my book)

$$1 - n e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + \frac{1}{2} n(n-1) e^{-t} + \cdots + (-1)^n e^{-\frac{nt}{2}}$$

Comment: If $F(s)$ is your function, then $F(s)=\frac{A_0}{2s}+\frac{A_1}{2s+1}+...+\frac{A_n}{2s+n}$. Note that $(2s+k)F(s)=A_k+(\text{ a multiple of }(2s+k))$. Taking limit as $s\to-k/2$ you get that $\frac{2n!}{(-k)(-k+1)...(-k+n)}=A_k$, where the denominator is missing the factor $-k+k$. Now compute inverse Laplace of each $\frac{A_k}{2s+k}$.

Comment: Whenever you have a rational function, that is something you can do; compute its [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) and then the inverse Laplace of each little resulting fraction.

Comment: $$ f_n(t) = e^{-\frac n2 t}\left(e^{\frac t2}-1\right)^n$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

$$
F_0(s) = \frac 1s\\
F_n(s) = \frac{n}{2s+n}F_{n-1}(s),\ \ \ n \gt 0
$$